# HTML Table. how to change thead height, when content rotate from horizontal to vertical mode

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have very simple code - HTML:

```
<thead style="height: 60px;">
  <tr class="position-relative">
    <th scope="col" style="width: 1.5em;"></th>
    <th scope="col" style="width: 2em;"></th>
    <th scope="col" style="width: 6em;"></th>
    <th scope="col"></th>
    <th scope="col" style="width: 1.5em;">
      <span class="tableNameSpan"> FirstName LastName 1 </span>
      <input type="checkbox" value="">
    </th>
    <th scope="col" style="width: 1.5em;">
      <span class="tableNameSpan"> FirstName LastName 2 </span>
      <input type="checkbox" value="">
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
```

CSS:

```
.tableNameSpan {
  position: relative;
  right: 15px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  margin-top: -400%;
}
```

Result

[image]

As you can see, there is an empty space between the paragraph and the checkboxes. It is formed because, initially, the names due to are converted into a column of letters (because `style="width: 1.5em;"`), and then I make them horizontal. The height is equal to the height of the letters of the longest name.

The main question is how to remove the empty space between the names and the paragraph.

force `height: 60px` doesn't work.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are allowed to change? Is the HTML and the CSS you give untouchable so you can only add some further CSS?

Comment: css can be changed.
html structure is fixed (number of columns and their width)